# What is the criteria for entering shell commands using Clojure Java Shell, specifically cd?

Tags: clojure

I have been trying a number of things to enter `cd /home/ics/icsdev` using Clojure Java Shell. I've been getting errors, but don't know why. I've read the source and looked for examples.

```
ics-db.core=> (sh "cmd" "cd /home/ics/icsdev")

    IOException error=2, 
 No such file or directory  
 java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec (UNIXProcess.java:-2)
```

I have also played around with `:in` and got this:

```
ics-db.core=> (:in "cd /home/ics/icsdev" (sh "pwd" ))
{:exit 0, :out "/home/ics/projects/clojure/ics-db\n", :err ""}
```

I wanted `pwd` to return /home/ics/icsdev.

In contrast, `pwd` works just fine

```
ics-db.core=> (sh "pwd")
{:exit 0, :out "/home/ics/projects/clojure/ics-db\n", :err ""}
ics-db.core=>
```

What am I missing?

Version of lein
Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_55 OpenJDK Client VM
Clojure 1.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the (bash) prompt

```
$ which pwd
/usr/bin/pwd

$ which cd
which: no cd in $PATH
```

You cannot directly exec a bash built-in like `cd` as a new process. It is a shell command, not an executable. This is why `(sh "pwd")` works but `(sh "cd" ...)` does not.

You can do so indirectly (Clojure REPL prompt)

```
=> (require '[clojure.java.shell :as shell])
=> (shell/sh "sh" "-c" "cd /etc; pwd")
{:exit 0, :out "/etc\n", :err ""}
```

But that just sets the directory in that new shell sub-process that has now exited.

Use `:dir` directive or `with-sh-dir` if you want to exec (multiple) process from within a different directories.

Comment: Thanks, and do you have a with-sh-dir example?

Comment: `(shell/with-sh-dir "../.." (shell/sh "touch" "test.txt") (shell/sh "ls" "test.txt"))`

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is a builtin in the `cmd` prompt. So, you can't execute it in this way, and even if you could, it wouldn't matter because it would change the current working directory of the sub-process, and not the JVM that is spawning the subprocess.